# iFrame and Background Html Control Overlapping Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i have a third party html page and an iframe page which is in my control i write html and js for that iframe but which click background html page its dropdow overlaps to my iframe how can i deal with it. i have tried triggering the click and focus event on my iframe page it will not work but when i click manually on my iframe my iframe come over the dropdown control.

i am attaching the snapshot of it.

[image: iFrame_Overlapping_Controls.png]

Comment: Create a small example or post a link to the website. Without any of the two, it would be very difficult to help. I suggest `z-index` should help, but I can't be very sure until I see something.

Comment: Is usually a `z-index` issue for sure. Easy enough to inspect in browser dev tools and edit live css to test